# Is there a way to set fields on the Sitecore Headless / JSS Settings for the site via environment variables?

Tags: jss, sxa-jss

Prior to `SXA-JSS` you could define the `JSS` Site settings in the config and therefore be able to use environment variables for things like the `serverSideRenderingEngineEndpointUrl`.

Is there a mechanism to continue doing this now that this setting has moved into the `/sitecore/content/Tenant/Site/Settings` item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is such a mechanism available where it will fall back to config files for values that are unset in the site settings item.

```
<sitecore>
    <javaScriptServices>
        <apps>
            <app name="site"
                sitecorePath="/sitecore/content/Tenant/Site"
                serverSideRenderingEngine="http"
                serverSideRenderingEngineEndpointUrl="$(env:EDITING_HOST)/api/editing/render"
                serverSideRenderingEngineApplicationUrl="$(env:RENDERING_HOST)"
                layoutServiceConfiguration="sxa-jss"
                inherits="defaults" />
        </apps>
    </javaScriptServices>
</sitecore>
```

It is important to make sure the `sitecorePath` matches correctly.